# VLAs at local scope works fine but at global space they don't

Tags: c++, g++

When the VLAs are declared in local space they work fine (unless -pedantic is used):

```
 int main()
 {
     int i=9;
     char n[i];   


     return 0;
 }
```

But when the same is done at global level it throws an error

```
int i=9;
char n[i];    //error: array bound is not an integer constant before ‘]’ token

int main()
{

     return 0;
}
```

- is it because the contents 
  of the local space are present in `stack` and contents in `static` memory require the size
  beforehand?

The compiler is **g++ (GCC) 8.2.0**

Comment: VLA are not C++, it's C99.

Comment: VLAs are *not* supported by standard C++ (some compilers accept them as *extensions* but they are *not* portable and should not be used). Use `std::vector` instead.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher TBF g++ supports it as a compiler extension.

Comment: *But when the same is done at global level it throws an error* -- VLA's in C++ are an invention of the compiler vendor.  Thus VLA's can behave any way they want outside of the obvious, and you have no say in the matter since it is not part of C++.